# Non-structured Query performs better than on clustered, hash-clustered and indexed?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, query-optimization, database-performance

I am using the following query as a base line on some unstructured data (no indexes, no clusters etc) and the query is performing better on the unstrutured data than when I add indexes to the join columns or add the tables to a cluster or hash-cluster. I feel my baseline query isn't ideal, my task is to take a baseline query and find a structure that performs the best with it but all the structures I have tried perform worse than the unstructured. Is there anything I can do to my baseline query that will at least find one structure that has a noticeable improvement over the unstructured?

Query:

```
SELECT Cust_name, price
FROM Customer, Sales
WHERE price > 1000
AND num_sold > 10
AND Sales.Cust_id = Customer.Cust_id;
```

This query is returning 108k+ rows out of 150k.

Here are the traces from the testing:

Unstructured:
[image]

With index added on the join columns Sales.Cust_id and Customer.Cust_id:
[image]

With both tables added to a cluster where the cluster index is the Cust_id:
[image]

With Both tables added to a hash cluster with 10000 keys:

[image]

Comment: Don't use comma syntax, use **JOIN** instead like: `SELECT Cust_name, price
FROM Customer c
JOIN  Sales s
   ON s.Cust_id = c.Cust_id
WHERE price > 1000
AND num_sold > 10;`

Comment: there were no exceptions running these queries, is there any difference in performance with structuring the query this way?

Comment: have you tried to execute the query with ``parallel`` hint?

Comment: I am going to do that after, but I just wanted to see what structure would work best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You select 72% of data. I don't think that any structure will help significantly for this scenario. The unstructured seems to be the best.

Comment: Can you suggest any improvements to the query? Or what I could use as a typical baseline query that could work with any of the structures?

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question. All depends on spec. If your users will select always 70 % of data (your baseline?) then you don't need any structure. However if your users will typically select 0.001% of data then you can define some efficient structures, etc.

Comment: I'm just meaning generally, the point of my baseline query was to get an initial reading which should be quite slow (so that I can see improvements later) such that I can change the structure and apply the same query and there should be atleast one structure that has better performance. The question asks if there is a better baseline query (i.e counting, fetching a single row, more/less filtering) that I could use because as you saw with my current query all the structures are worse

Comment: Get the typical query(ies) from the user. Nobody will guess it. Each structue is good for something else - there is no solution for evrything :) if there would be one structure perfect for evrything then there would exists only the one.

Answer (score 0):

The only methods I can think of for improving this are:

1. Range partitioning the sales table on either price, num_sold, or both.
2. Using a materialized view to prejoin the tables, and/or limit the columns required, and/or limit the rows required.
3. Use a form of compression on the sales table (which might only be valuable if you bulk-insert sales using direct path).
4. Maybe try a compressed index on the columns of the sales table that you use, and maybe use an index on customer (cust_id, cust_name), and hope for fast full index scans.